# I'd like to create CloudFormation stack with resources in multiple regions. Is this possible?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create a single Amazon CloudFormation stack template that instantiates an `AWS::EC2::Instance` in `ap-southeast-1` and another `AWS::EC2::Instance` in `us-west-2` for example?

I suspect not, but I've not yet found a definitive yes/no saying that stacks can't have resources spanning multiple regions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very good question; but I don't think you would be able to create resources spread across multiple regions.

The end point URL for CloudFormation is region based and AFAIK there isn't a place whether you can specify an region specific (diff region) information.

As of today you can compose the CloudFormation template in such way to make it region independent by leveraging the mappings section and `get::region` function; but making the template spread across multiple regions simultaneously wouldn't be possible; but can be expected down the line.

Comment: You now have CloudFormation StackSets that would allow deployment in multiple regions, and multiple accounts as well. https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/stacksets/home?region=eu-west-1#/stacksets

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer is out of date. It is now possible to create stacks across accounts and regions using [CloudFormation StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-getting-started.html).

Comment: Can you provide a light sample within you response?

Comment: The only thing I've faced is this issue (https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2249) that requires a lot of extra actions for rather complex templates with dependencies

Comment: The only problem is : you can't use outputs of stackset template in main template

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet right now would be to use a Cloudformation Custom Resource that invokes a Lambda function in order to create the resources that are in other regions. When you run the CFN template it would invoke the Lambda function where you'd create code (Python, Node.js or Java) that leverages the AWS SDKs to create the resources you need. CFN Custom Resources allow you to pass parameters to the function and get "outputs" back from them so from a CFN perspective you can treat it just like any other resource.

Here's a walkthrough example from the AWS docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html

Comment: Wouldn't the Lambda need to be deployed in each region where a caller could invoke the template from, though?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lambda function invoking to create a resource in another region, and even making your lambda function to invoke another stack in the other region.

To make your life easy, in this case you can use the lambda [cli2cloudformation](https://github.com/lucioveloso/cli2cloudformation) (https://github.com/lucioveloso/cli2cloudformation).

Using it, you can execute CLI commands inside your lambda, and by this way, you specific the --region in the command.

It's also interesting, because you will be able to set a command when your stack is created, updated and deleted.

```
  "myCustomResource": {
    "Type": "Custom::LocationConstraint",
    "Properties": {
      "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:432811670411:function:cli2cfn_proxy2",
      "CliCommandCreate": "s3api get-bucket-location --bucket my-test-bucket --region eu-west-1",
      "CliCommandUpdate": "",
      "CliCommandDelete": ""
    }
  },
```